# Laravel Custom SMS provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sms, sms-gateway

I'm trying to implement SMS notifications in my system that is built with Laravel. I cannot use Nexmo nor Twilio, so I think I have to create a custom driver for my SMS provider. Any ideas on how to go about that?

Comment: Why you cannot use NEXMO?

Comment: my boss said so. We have a local SMS provider that we have a contract with

Comment: Do they have an api and/or a php package that you can install?

Answer (score 2):

Hate to blow my own trumpet, but I wrote my own [SMS client library](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/sms-client) that supports swappable drivers, including a generic mail driver that you can use if your provider offers a mail to SMS gateway.

If your provider isn't supported, but offers a REST API, you could fork it and implement your own driver for it, using the existing ones as a template. Your driver class should implement the `Driver` interface, like the existing ones do, and use Guzzle to make the request. Or you can just lift the parts you need or use it as inspiration. Without knowing more about the provider in question I can't really give any more advice, but in theory either using the mail driver or adding a new driver for a REST API should be fairly simple. If you do create a working driver, feel free to submit a pull request so I can add it to the package.

There's also a Laravel-specific integration package for it, but that won't support any custom drivers you add (although it will work with the mail driver). However it wouldn't be hard to integrate it with Laravel yourself as it's just a matter of creating a service provider to set up the client class.

Alternatively, if they offer an off the shelf package, I would just use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Laravel SMS API plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/gr8shivam/laravel-sms-api) for sending text messages using your local SMS provider.

The plugin also integrates with Laravel notification system.